# Groupby and xtract aggregated median values of a Spark DF

Tags: python, function, loops, apache-spark

[code link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTdIF.png)

from transforms.api import transform, Input, Output

import pyspark.sql.functions as f

@transform(

```
output1=Output("/Buyers/clean/median_750_buyers"),
output2=Output("/Buyers/clean/cleaned/split_purchase_log_data", sever_permissions=True),
my_input=Input("/Buyers/raw_data/purchase_log"),
```

def get_median_750_buyers(ctx, my_input, output1, output2):

```
my_input = my_input.dataframe()
```

# group by buyer_name,continent and clothing item and extract the 25 median buyers from each of the 30 possible combinations

```
 df = my_input.groupby('buyer_name', 'continent','clothing_items') \
             .count() \
             .select("buyer_name", f.col('count').alias('buyer_name_count')) \
             .sort(f.desc("buyer_name_count"))

# get the total row in the new dataframe
rowCount = df.count()
```

I have a spark dataframe that is 1,000,000 rows of purchase records with over 50,000 unique buyers of 5 different types of clothing apparell that gets purchased from 6 continents

6 Continents : (N.America,Europe,Asia, Africa, S.America, Australia)

5 Clothing Item :(Hat,Pants,T-Shirt, Coat,Socks)

I want to get from each combination of 6 Continents and 5 clothing items = (30 combinations) a dataframe of the 25 buyers names that are closest to the median value when you groupby the buyer_name column. So this would be a total of 750 buyers and all of the rows of their purchase data extracted and saved to a dataframe called "750_median_buyers".

The ask is to have this done with pyspark code. 
Thanks any help is much appreciated!

Comment: how about making an attempt?

Comment: what did you try till now?